# Query Google Spreadsheet with Miso Dataset or other JS library?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, miso.dataset

I would like to use a Google Spreadsheet as a simple database.

Can I query for specific cells using Miso Dataset or another JavaScript library? I have seen Tabletop.js but I can't get the query part to work. (It fetches the full sheet or nothing ...)

Answer (score 1):

I know this man created js library for google spreadsheet here: https://github.com/mikeymckay/google-spreadsheet-javascript

Answer (score 0):

CSV:

if you can make the spreadsheet public, this will work:

[jquery google spreadsheet csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264172/jquery-google-spreadsheet-csv)

If login is required, I think there is a way to do web based OAuth, but never used it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard API to get certain cells:  [Google Spreadsheet API - Working with Cell-based feeds](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#working_with_cell-based_feeds).  Make sure to click the "Protocol" tab for the Javascript version.